# Can I conclude a statement is true if it leads to no false arguments?

Tags: logic, optimization, linear-programming, boolean

From a logic point of view, if I have a hypothesis and then define a condition (I still have no idea if its true or not) related to that hypothesis and show that defining in that way leads to no contradiction in the original hypothesis, can I conclude the condition is actually true?

I tried to prove the equivalence of two mathematical models, I then stated a formula that correlates both models variables and showed that defining in that way leads to no contradiction in both models constraints. Does that mean my equivalence affirmation is true or I am missing something?

Comment: The continuum hypothesis leads to no contradictions in ZFC; that doesn't mean it's true, though, just independent of ZFC. Maybe it's true, maybe it's not, but we can't prove such from the axioms of ZFC.

Comment: If I want to construct a contradiction to $A \implies B$ I am required to evaluate the relationship between the $A$ and $B$ statements. If I merely posit $A$ there is nothing to contradict, so in isolation you can say almost anything. I say almost because paradoxes aren't really false and aren't really true either. Those require some care.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, I think I have managed to  find the specific polyhedral extreme points and therefore establish a relationship between the models, thanks for the help.